# creating a set associative array

Tags: c++, set, associative-array

I want to create a set associative structure similar to cache (http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Memory/set.html). There are some sets and each set contains some ways. Each way has some fields however all of the ways in a set has unique field (tag).

I see `std::multiset` which can be used for my purpose. Is there any other choice? any thought?

Comment: Seems more like you want a map of maps/sets/lists (depending on what it is you're trying to do, perhaps a little more detail might help here).  Multisets may not be great for your purposes because you want a key (the tag in this case) and multiple values.

Comment: can you give an example of "map of sets"? I mean the insert/find/delete prcedures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For caches I usually use std::map, std::multimap or their hash equivelents. In fact hash_map usually performs a bit better so probably it is the better choice here. In c++11 hash_map is called [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and is now part of the standard so I advice you to use this one. It also has a multi- version called [unordered_multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap). If c++11 is not an option same containers can be found in boost.